# Find a function $f(x)$ such that $\forall \epsilon \gt 0, f(x) = f(x + \epsilon)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Our professor asked us if we can find a function $f(x)$ such that $\forall \epsilon \gt 0, f(x) = f(x + \epsilon)$. In other words, a function that it's periodic no matter how small you pick the period $\epsilon$.

He also said that:

1. The constant function $f(x) = c$ satisfies the above equation, but he's looking for another one.
2. This function cannot be plotted or something like that, I didn't understand this part.

Any hints on this?

**EDIT**: So, as I was expecting, when $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$, only constant functions are valid solutions.

What about the case $\epsilon \in \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: As stated I don't think there is such an example, simply because if your result is true for every real $x$ and positive $\varepsilon$ then it is easy to choose $x,\varepsilon$ appropriately to get $f(y)=f(z)$ for arbitrary $y,z$. Are you sure $\varepsilon$ is not constrained to be rational? Because I think there are pathological non-constant solutions in this case, similar to the situation with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation There you have a different slope for each copy of the rationals; here you would have a different constant for each copy of the rationals.

Comment: You might be right, there may be constraints that I didn't hear.

Comment: He may well have asked for a function that is periodic for arbitrarily small periods, i.e. $\forall \epsilon > 0$ $\exists \delta$ s.t. $\epsilon > \delta > 0$ and $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, f(x) = f(x + \delta)$. In which case e.g. the characteristic function of the rationals works.

Comment: @user73985: Your hypothesis could be valid as well. By "the characteristic function of the rationals" do you mean $$f(x) = \left \{ \begin{align} &0 \qquad \text{if $x$ is rational}\\ &1 \qquad \text{otherwise}\end{align} \right .$$ ?

Comment: Yes. Well, probably the other way around ($1$ on rationals and $0$ on irrationals) but either works as an answer.

Comment: @user73985: The professor confirmed that one of the possible answers was the Drichlet function, so you were right!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x\in \Bbb R$ and put $\varepsilon=y-x$, for any $y>x$. Then $f(x)=f(x+\varepsilon)=f(y)$. Since $y>x$ was arbitrary, we conclude that $f(x)=f(y)$ for every $y>x$. Now, as $x\in\Bbb R$ was arbitrary, we conclude that $f(x)=f(y)$ for all $x,y\in\Bbb R$, that is, the only functions satisfying the property are constant functions.

Comment: Very interesting. What about the more restrictive case in which $\epsilon \in \mathbb{Q}$?